# Request.user is a SimpleLazyObject after authenticating

Tags: django

I'm not entirely sure why. I've read previous similar questions about this and the consensus is that you need to "user" request.user before it actually becomes a User object...but I have. I have the code

```
if request.user.is_authenticated()   
    context.update({'username':request.user['username']})
```

But I keep getting a **'SimpleLazyObject' object has no attribute '_*getitem*_'** error when trying to access the username field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Username is accessible as an attribute (`request.user` is either `auth.User` instance, or `AnonymousUser` instance with similar interface). Try this:

```py
if request.user.is_authenticated()   
    context.update({'username': request.user.username})
```